# How to duplicate and rename an entire web application/solution/project in VS 2013?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I thought this would be quite easy!  Maybe it is and I'm approaching it all wrong.

I have a "base" web app that I'm starting with.  Let's call it solution/project abc.  It lives in inetpub/wwwroot/abc/ and that folder has the abc.sln, abc.suo and single project folder (also called abc) in there.

I want to duplicate this entire folder, solution and project and call it xyz, so that I still have the existing abc solution/project but I also have xyz solution and project.

So far I have created an empty web app called xyz.  I then copied/pasted the project folder abc from solution folder abc and renamed the folder "xyz" and the project file in there "xyz.vbproj".  I then "add existing project" to my xyz solution and all looks good.  I then edit properties and change namespaces to "xyz" from "abc".  I also change the logo and some header text from abclogo to xyzlogo.

I then build the project and get my first problem: "The discovered startup type 'xyz.Startup, sustain, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' conflicts with the type 'abc.Startup"

Also when I now try and build/run my existing abc solution/project, that now starts failing with errors relating to conflicting startup types, referring to "xyz.startup" but there is no reference or even occurence of "xyz" anywhere in my "abc" solution, so I have no idea why there is a conflict here. It's like there's some kind of link remaining.

If I "build" my abc project and run it again, it works. If I switch to the other project and build/run it, it breaks my previously-working abc project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to copy/paste a solution's entire folder to a completely different location, and as long as you've updated all references to the old path to the new one, it should work. So there's no real problem with the way you approach it.

The most likely explanation is that there is some leftover reference to the old path somewhere in your new folder. Here's what I would do:

(assuming the abc solution lives in "c:\abc" and you want to duplicate it as "c:\xyz")

1. copy/paste folder "c:\abc" to "c:\xyz"
2. below "c:\xyz", rename all files that contain an "abc" to contain "xyz" instead
3. below "c:\xyz", delete *.suo
4. open Visual Studio (without opening a solution!), and do a **Replace In Files** like this:

   - Folder: "c:\xyz"
   - Filetypes: *.*
   - From: "abc"
   - To: "xyz"
5. open solution "c:\xyz\xyz.sln" and rebuild all

Comment: Ah. Well I think I was almost there. I think there was a legacy dll knocking about in the bin and I also needed to go into web properties and make sure it used a different local dev port number for testing.  It's now working ok, thanks.